# How to sort an array of objects without sequentially repeating two specific properties in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have the following array of objects with *from* and *to* properties:

```
[
    {order: 0, from: 'Birigui', to: 'Penápolis'},
    {order: 1, from: 'Birigui', to: 'Araçatuba'},
    {order: 2, from: 'Avanhandava', to: 'Penápolis'},
    {order: 3, from: 'Avanhandava', to: 'Araçatuba'},
    {order: 4, from: 'Penápolis', to: 'Araçatuba'},
    {order: 5, from: 'Birigui', to: 'Avanhandava'},
    {order: 6, from: 'Marilia', to: 'São Paulo'},
    {order: 7, from: 'Marilia', to: 'Birigui'},
    {order: 8, from: 'Marilia', to: 'Penápolis'},
]
```

**I need to sort this array in a way that the i-th element in the sequence never contains the same *from* and *to* as its previous and its next element.**

For example, if the first item in the list contains 'Birigui' and 'Penápolis', the second item can't contain 'Birigui' or 'Penápolis' neither in *from* nor in *to*

The ordered list would look like this:

```
[
    {order: 0, from: 'Birigui', to: 'Penápolis'},
    {order: 1, from: 'Marilia', to: 'São Paulo'},
    {order: 2, from: 'Birigui', to: 'Araçatuba'},
    {order: 3, from: 'Avanhandava', to: 'Penápolis'},
    {order: 4, from: 'Marilia', to: 'Birigui'},
    {order: 5, from: 'Penápolis', to: 'Araçatuba'},
    {order: 6, from: 'Birigui', to: 'Avanhandava'},
    {order: 7, from: 'Marilia', to: 'Penápolis'},
    {order: 8, from: 'Avanhandava', to: 'Araçatuba'},
]
```

What's a good way to achieve this?

---

## Solved

I find the solution:

```js
const from = [
  'Penápolis',
  'Araçatuba',
  'Birigui',
  'Avanhandava',
  'Venezuela',
]

const to = [
  'Japão',
  'Penápolis',
  'Venezuela',
  'Italia',
  'China',
]

let combinations = []

// Make combinations with all 'from' and all 'to'
from.forEach(fromCity => {
  to.forEach(toCity => {
    if (
      combinations.some(combination => combination.from === fromCity && combination.to === toCity) === false &&
      combinations.some(combination => combination.from === toCity && combination.to === fromCity) === false &&
      fromCity !== toCity) {
      combinations.push({from: fromCity, to: toCity})
    }
  })
})

// Create an array with unique city names
let cities = [...from, ...to]
const unique = function(arr) {
  var a = arr.concat()
  for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
      for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
        if(a[i] === a[j]) a.splice(j--, 1)
      }
  }
  return a
}
cities = unique(cities)

// Split cities in  groups
let groups = {}
while (combinations.length > 0) {
  cities.forEach(city => {
    if (groups[city] === undefined) groups[city] = []
    combinations.forEach((combination, index) => {
      if (combination.from === city || combination.to === city) {
        let removed = combinations.splice(index, 1)
        groups[city].push(...removed)
      }
    })
  })
}

// Sort city names by group length
cities.sort((a, b) => groups[b].length - groups[a].length)

// Make an array ordened by cities to push ordered in the list
let combinationsToPush = []
cities.forEach(city => combinationsToPush.push(...groups[city]))

// Sort the final list
let list = []
while (combinationsToPush.length > 0) {
  combinationsToPush.forEach((combination, index) => {
    // If list is empty, just add
    if (list.length === 0) list.push(...combinationsToPush.splice(index, 1))
    // If not...
    let i = 0
    // If first element of list is different, just add
    if (list[i].from !== combination.from && list[i].to !== combination.from && list[i].from !== combination.to && list[i].to !== combination.to) {
      list.splice(i, 0, ...combinationsToPush.splice(index, 1))
    // If not, run the entire list to find a place to put combination
    } else {
      while (i < list.length - 2) {
        i++
        if (list[i].from !== combination.from && list[i].to !== combination.from && list[i].from !== combination.to && list[i].to !== combination.to
          && list[i+1].from !== combination.from && list[i+1].to !== combination.from && list[i+1].from !== combination.to && list[i+1].to !== combination.to) {
            list.splice(i+1, 0, ...combinationsToPush.splice(index, 1))
        }
      }
    }
    // If not find a place to put the combination, the combination will wait for the next while run
  })
}
console.log(list)
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Maybe it's not possible.  Like, maybe you simply can't make that structure out of the data you're given.

Comment: Question general improvements

Comment: I edited the question but I agree with @CertainPerformance.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake... Well, the answer of @MarkMeyer cleared my mind, so I could find the solution. I'll edit my question with the solution. Oh, and sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Please post your solution in an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to break up all the items by `from` sorted by how many are in the group. Start with the largest group and  interleave the other groups in order. It's possible for the largest groups to have more members than all the others combined, in which case your sort is not possible.

```js
let arr = [{order: 0, from: 'Birigui', to: 'Penápolis'},{order: 1, from: 'Birigui', to: 'Araçatuba'},{order: 2, from: 'Avanhandava', to: 'Penápolis'},{order: 3, from: 'Avanhandava', to: 'Araçatuba'},{order: 4, from: 'Penápolis', to: 'Araçatuba'},{order: 5, from: 'Birigui', to: 'Avanhandava'},{order: 6, from: 'Marilia', to: 'São Paulo'},{order: 7, from: 'Marilia', to: 'Birigui'},{order: 8, from: 'Marilia', to: 'Penápolis'},]

// group and sort by group length
let counts = Object.values(arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    (obj[item.from] || (obj[item.from] = [])).push(item)
    return obj
}, {})).sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)

// take largest group (broken into individual arrays)
let main = counts.shift().map(c => [c])

// take all others as a large group and interveave into main group
let rest = counts.reduce((arr, item) => arr.concat([...item]))
rest.forEach((item, i) => main[i % main.length].push(item))

// flatten the structure and correct the order numbers
let final = main.reduce((arr, item) => arr.concat([...item]))
final.forEach((item, i) => item.order = i)

 console.log(final)
```

You can probably compress some of those steps into single steps — just spelled out in individual steps to be clear.